# Odoo 14 on windows can't enable LDAP Authentication

Tags: python, windows, odoo, python-ldap, pyldap

I tried to enable LDAP Authentication on ODOO 14 which is install on Windows Server and when click save i got the following error

```
"Error:
 Odoo Server Error

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
  result = request.dispatch()
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\http.py", line 683, in dispatch
  result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\http.py", line 359, in _call_function
  return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
  return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\http.py", line 347, in checked_call
  result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\http.py", line 912, in __call__
  return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\http.py", line 531, in response_wrap
  response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1393, in call_button
  action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1381, in _call_kw
  return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\api.py", line 396, in call_kw
  result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
  result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\base\models\res_config.py", line 642, in execute
  installation_status = self._install_modules(to_install)
  File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\base\models\res_config.py", line 36, in _ 
    install_modules
 result = to_install_modules.button_immediate_install()
 File "<decorator-gen-71>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 73, in check_and_log
 return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 474, in 
 button_immediate_install
 return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 592, in 
_button_immediate_function
 modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 89, in new
 odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 455, in load_modules
 loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 348, in load_marked_modules
 perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 178, in load_module_graph
 load_openerp_module(package.name)
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\modules\module.py", line 358, in load_openerp_module
 __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\auth_ldap\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
 from . import models
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\auth_ldap\models\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
 from . import res_company_ldap
 File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\addons\auth_ldap\models\res_company_ldap.py", line 6, in 
 <module>
  from ldap.filter import filter_format
  Exception

  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
   return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
   File "C:\inetpub\ARCOMERP\server\odoo\http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
   raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldap.filter'"
```

after my investigation I try to install PyLDAP library by several ways but its not working. for my big issue now how to install pyldap on windows

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you may resolve with following:

> python -m pip install python-ldap

For Window, you may check [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) documentation but I never personally install package in window.